# Is there a posibility to check if the Object i am into is there but pointing at Null?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, binary-tree

I want to write a recursive method to put a binary tree in-order into an arrays, the sheet I got from my University told me I should write the method inside of a nested class "node" and let the outerclass call that Method in a new Method.

but the recursive method has to have its basis, and I can't ask if ( node == null ) because I am already inside the Class Node.
and (this == null) also doesn't seem quite right.

Edit:

I think I got what you are trying to say and I understood it, kind of.
As you were asking I am giving you the part of the code I am referring to.

```
public class BinaryIntTree {

public static class Node {
    
    int value;
    
    Node leftChild;
    
    Node rightChild;
    
    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    /**
     * Performs an in order traversal and writes the
     * values of the tree into the array starting at
     * the specified start index. When done, the
     * method returns the updated start index that
     * is incremented by the number of values written
     * to the array.
     * 
     * @param array The array to write to.
     * @param startIndex The start index to write from.
     * @return The updated start index that is incremented
     *  by the number of values written to the array.
     */
    public int toArray(int[] array, int startIndex) {
        
    return 0;
    }
}
public int[] toIntArray() {
    int[] result = new int[getNodeCount()];
    if (result.length != 0) {
        root.toArray(result, 0);
    }
    return result;
  } 


}
```

There was a bit more methods in it which I deleted to point out the part I am struggling with.
Usually I did normal in-order traversal in the Binarytree class but our Prof now wants us to do it inside the nested class and let it be called in the outer class like you can see here.

I also cant figure out how I am supposed to go deeper into the tree when I cant even put a leftChild or a rightChild inside of the methods parameter which is supposed to be recursive in the nested Class.
I am not supposed to change the parameter or make the method static.

I hope I could describe it well enough.

Comment: if the class method is being called, then its object exists. other wise you would get a `NullPointerException` when you attempt to invoke the method.

Comment: You are right that `this == null` isn't correct.  `this` can never be `null`.  However, neither you description of your task, or your description of the solution you are thinking of is clear enough for us to respond to.  (It might help if you showed us your code ...)

Comment: In order traversal means first visiting the left child nodes (if there are any), then visiting the current node and after that visiting the right child nodes (if there are any). Visiting the left child nodes (if there are any) translates into `if (leftChild != null) /* try to insert the recursive call yourself */;`. Visiting the current nodes translates into `array[startIndex++] = value;`. Visiting the right child nodes is similar to visiting the left child nodes - I'm shure by now you're able to solve this. As you see the null check needs to be done by the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Each node in your tree is a different instance of the `Node` class. The `Node` class likely has two `Node` type fields for its left and right child. You want to be doing this `null` check on that left and right child, and not on the current node (since the current node `this` always exists).